# Full Text difference between SQL Server and Postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, full-text-search

I have access (*no source code*) to webservice to do street and poi search, the back end is using PostgreSQL. Is very good and accurated. Can weight the words to match `State` or `City`, know when is a `Street` or a `Building`

If I search:

> "calle 15 lomas del avila"
>   - "calle" mean STREET
>   - "lomas del avila" is a sector in Caracas city.
>   Found a Bus station and the street name "calle 15"

[image]

Now we got some source code for a `SQL Server 2012` version from the **same provider** as webservice. And this time I have the code.

But the result I get from the store procedure are very generic and return lot of result. Looks like the rank value is off because the better match appear on position 5 and 6

[image]

Provider claim PostgreSQL is smarter that MSQL and can weight the words in better way. So the different result are caused by different engine.

I'm on the process of understand the MSQL code. But that claim make sense?

Is Postgresql text-search smarter than MSQL? I mean have both same capabilities or one have limit functionality. In postgres I know have some rank funcionality to make some part more importants.

Comment: "*Is Postgresql text-search smarter than MSQL*" - I haven't used the SQL Server full text search, but I wouldn't be surprised if that was indeed the case.

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name I continue testing sql version. Have any postgres link regarding text-search you can share?